# SQL. Запрос на вывод самых актуальных значений

Tags: sql, mariadb

Имеются две таблицы (Версия сервера: 10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 - Ubuntu 22.04) со следующим содержимым:

Таблица **sensors**

| sensor_id | sensor_adress |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03173311a0ff |
| 2 | xxxxxxxxxxxx |

...и таблица **measurements**

| measurement_id | sensor_id | temperature_value | measurement_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 18.567 | 2024-03-10 19:00:30 |
| 2 | 2 | 19.123 | 2024-03-10 19:00:40 |
| 3 | 1 | 20.0 | 2024-03-10 20:00:30 |
| 4 | 2 | 22.5 | 2024-03-10 20:00:40 |

**Задача:**
Вывести самую актуальную температуру (temperature_value) по всем датчикам и адрес сенсора (sensor_adress), т.е. что-то в этом роде:

| sensor_adress | temperature_value |
| --- | --- |
| 03173311a0ff | 20.0 |
| xxxxxxxxxxxx | 22.5 |

Пробовал составить SQL-запрос, получилось вот что:

```
SELECT `sensors`.`sensor_adress`, `measurements`.`temperature_value`
FROM `measurements` INNER JOIN `sensors`
ON `sensors`.`sensor_id` = `measurements`.`sensor_id`
WHERE `measurements`.`measurement_time` = (SELECT MAX(`measurement_time`) FROM `measurements`)
ORDER BY `sensors`.`sensor_id` ASC;
```

Как мне улучшить подзапрос

```
SELECT MAX(`measurement_time`) FROM `measurements`
```

чтобы была выборка не по максимальному TIMESTAMP, а именно по самому актуальному для каждого датчика?

Comment: если  у вас инкрементальные id измерений, то можете выбрать `sensor_id, max(id) .. group by sensor_id`  а потом к этой производной таблице/цте приджойнить реальную с данными. С другой стороны у вас актуальная версия СУБД, поддерживающая оконные функции, так что подобные задачи решаются нурмеацией строк в нужной сортировке и выборкой строк с номером 1. Можете, конечно и коррелирующие запросы на максимум оставить, добавив условие в свой подзапрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения подобных задач обычно имеются следующие варианты:

1. использование производной таблицы/общего табличного выражения с группировкой для поиска максимального значения для сенсора, и джойн этого добра на саму таблицу данных. Примерно так:

   ```
   SELECT s.address, d.temperature_value
   FROM sensors AS s 
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT sensor_id, max(id) as id
      FROM measurements
      GROUP BY sensor_id
   ) AS m ON (m.sensor_id = s.id)
   INNER JOIN measurements AS d ON (d.id = m.id)

   # ---- либо аналогичный CTE
   WITH m AS (
       SELECT sensor_id, MAX(id) AS id
       ....
   )
   SELECT 
   FROM sensors AS s 
   INNER JOIN m ....
   ```

   тип джойнов тут будет определять, что первично, список имеющихся данных или сенсоров.
2. Оконные функции и нумерация строк

   ```
   WITH data AS (
      SELECT sensor_id
          , temperature_value
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sensor_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
      FROM measurements AS m
   ) 
   SELECT s.address, data.temperature_value
   FROM data 
   INNER JOIN sensors AS s ON (s.id = data.sensor_id)
   WHERE rn = 1
   ```
3. Коррелирующий подзапрос,который возвращает единственное значение температуры для сенсора:

   ```
   SELECT s.address
       , (SELECT temperature_value
          FROM measurements AS m
          WHERE m.sensor_id = s.id
          ORDER BY id DESC 
          LIMIT 1) AS t
   FROM sensors AS s
   ```
4. Если же кроме одного значения надо вытащить и другие данные из строк, то подзапрос уходит в джойн

   ```
    SELECT s.address, m.temperature_value
    FROM sensors AS s 
    LEFT JOIN measurements AS m ON (
          m.id = (SELECT MAX(id) 
                  FROM measurements AS m 
                  WHERE m.sensor_id = s.id)
    )
   ```

*Для вашего случая и желаемого результата, видимо самым простым будет вариант под номером 3.*

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Буду разбираться!